# UITableVIew indexPathsForVisibleRows

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode6, grand-central-dispatch

In the callback function ,sometime app will crash when calling the indexPathsForVisibleRows and then calling reloadRowsAtIndexPaths.

In my case, default has the 6 number of items. If the callback function do the above thing repeatedly, app will crash.

Code:

```
-(void) asyncimageloader:(AsyncImageLoader *)loader withImage:(UIImage *)image withIndex:(NSIndexPath *)index withKey:(NSString *)key
{

    NSArray *paths = [self.mtableview indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    for(int i=0 ;i< [paths count] ;i++)
    {
        NSIndexPath *p  = [paths objectAtIndex:i];

        if (p.section == index.section && p.row == index.row) {   


             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [self.mtableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath  
                indexPathForRow:index.row inSection:index.section], nil] 
                withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

             });
         }
     }
}
```

Crash Log: sometime show log1 , sometime show log2

Log1: attempt to insert row 1 into section 0, but there are only 6 rows in section 0 after the update

Log2: request for rect at invalid index path ( {length = 2, path = 0 - 1})

Thanks for help!!

Comment: You should post your full stack trace.

Comment: If you reloadRows callest. the cells are cleared and reset. So your code accesses objects that no longer exist.

Comment: Thanks for help.
I have solve the problem. I think this is because the race condition of thread. In my case, there is the shared data (data array) for uitableview numberOfRowsInSection ,cellForRowAtIndexPath etc. And i use async-image loader that reloads the image with specific index path when loading success. So i have to keep the sequence of threads for ui updating.